# I want to open google.com or any other website that a user types in a window

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code which opens the user input 
but the problem is 
it opens it like
127.0.0.1:8887/www.google.com

what changes should i do so that it directly just opens
www.google.com

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
label {
display:block;
}
</style>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"
integrity="sha256-BTlTdQO9/fascB1drekrDVkaKd9PkwBymMlHOiG+qLI="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function goTo() {
    var url = document.forms[0].url.value;
    myWindow = window.open(url, "", "width=800,height=800");
    myWindow.focus();
    return false;
}

$('.url').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
        goto();
    }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return goTo()">
    <label for="url">Enter the URL:
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the URL doesn't have a protocol, prepend `//` to it. You can use `new URL(url);` to parse the URL and get properties from it.

Comment: jump menu may help you https://www.abeautifulsite.net/unobtrusive-jump-menus-using-javascript

Comment: input should be https://www.google.com    because of that's it causing issu4=e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the protocol (eg `https` or `http` to the url so that it knows it is not a sub url). Try it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
label {
display:block;
}
</style>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"
integrity="sha256-BTlTdQO9/fascB1drekrDVkaKd9PkwBymMlHOiG+qLI="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function goTo() {
    var url = document.forms[0].url.value;
    if(!(url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")))
        url = "//"+url; //<-- Adds protocol

    myWindow = window.open(url, "", "width=800,height=800"); 
    myWindow.focus();
    return false;
}

$('.url').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
        goto();
    }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return goTo()">
    <label for="url">Enter the URL:
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Changed it. @hlozancic

Comment: Now you are forcing http :) Just add //

Comment: Still not his question though

Answer (score 1):

You need the protocol information in your url.

You can check if user already typed `http://` or `https://` and if he didn't, add `//`:

```
url = /^https?:\/\//i.test(url) ? url : '//' + url
myWindow = window.open(url, "", "width=800,height=800");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function goTo() {
        var url = 'http://'+document.forms[0].url.value;
        myWindow = window.open(url, "", "width=800,height=800");
        myWindow.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If user already entered http or https this will not work. You should check this before prepending protocol

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user entered https://  if not, add it to the entered URL

Answer (score -2):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
label {
display:block;
}
</style>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"
integrity="sha256-BTlTdQO9/fascB1drekrDVkaKd9PkwBymMlHOiG+qLI="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function goTo() {
    var url = "http://"+document.forms[0].url.value;
    myWindow = window.open(url, "", "width=800,height=800");
    myWindow.focus();
    return false;
}

$('.url').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
        goto();
    }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return goTo()">
    <label for="url">Enter the URL:
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```